# Calling a C++ function that takes a char pointer from C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, dllimport, dllexport

I cant figure out how to pass a char * to this C++ function from C#.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
unsigned int extractSegment(char * startPoint, unsigned int sizeToExtract)
{
//do stuff
shared_ptr<std::vector<char>> content(new std::vector<char>(startPoint,startPoint+sizeToExtract));
//do more stuff
return content->size();
}
```

This function is used to read a segment from a file and do some binary operations on it (why i use the vector of chars). The startPoint is the start of the segment i want to read. I cannot change this function.

In C# I tried reading the file into a byte[] array and defining the DllImport to use StringBuilder where the export had char *. I tried to call it as such:

```
byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(arr, startPoint,arr.Length - startPoiunt));
extractSegment(sb,200);
```

This resulted in SEHException.

Comment: You probably forgot CallingConvention.Cdecl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char *` can have several different meanings. In your case it appears to be a preallocated and filled array of bytes that is used as an input parameter for the `extractSegment` function.

The equivalent C# method would then take a `byte[]` parameter, i.e.

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern int extractSegment(byte[] startPoint, uint sizeToExtract);
```

I use `byte[]` because you mention *binary operations*, however if it is actually a string then you can also marshal it as such, setting the correct encoding in the `DllImport` attribute.

---

And just for further information, other possible options for `char *` that I can think of right now would be `ref byte`, `out byte`, `ref char`, `out char` or `string`. `StringBuilder` on the other hand is used when the calling function allocates and returns a string, i.e. `char **`.

Comment: Okay, but how do I get the byte array (startPoint) with an offset, seeing as pointers are unsafe. I dont want to make a copy of the subarray every time...

Comment: @Oliver I don't know if there is any method available that doesn't involve creating a new array. It might be worth asking a new question.

Comment: Then use `ref byte` and pass `ref array[index]`.